# asp.net tree view selectd node value using javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, treeview

hi i am using a treeview control in my page i am binding the treeview with the datatable

i need to use javascript to get the selected node value on the tree in a button click.
how to do this

Comment: Can you show me your how u are populating treeview Control?

Answer (score 2):

When you bind your tree, use the navigateURL property of each node to call a JavaScript function.

When you bind:

```
newNode.NavigateUrl = "javascript:clickNode(this, '" + someObject.ID.ToString() + "');
```

On the client:

```
var selectedNode;
var selectedValue;

function clickNode(sender, id)
{         

    selectedNode = sender;
    selectedValue = id;

    //do other stuff here       
}
```